# how to soft delete using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a very simple model with a "deleted" column (1/0)

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            required: true
        },
        deleted: {
            type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
            allowNull: false,
            required: true,
            defaultValue: 0,
        },
    });

    return User;
}
```

in my router I list all the users

```
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {

    return models.User.findAll({where: {deleted: 0})
        .then(users => res.status(200).json(users))
});
```

is there a way to define the **deleted = 0** as part of the model itself so I dont have to pass it on every time I need to list the users? thank you!

Comment: why not `paranoid`?  https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html

Comment: thanks @Emma that´s what I´m looking for. it was in the documentation the whole time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `paranoid:true` in your model.

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            required: true
        },
        deleted: {
            type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
            allowNull: false,
            required: true,
            defaultValue: 0,
        },
    },{
       paranoid: true
    });
```

Comment: yup. doing this I don't need the deleted key. thanks!